# How do you iterate over a cursor in Snowflake Scripting?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-cursor

I'm translating stored procedure from TSQL to Snowflake Scripting and I'm stuck on an iteration of a cursor.

I tried looking at the API but couldn't find any exemple applicable to this situation.

**The original code in TSQL:**

```
OPEN C_procedure;  
        
FETCH NEXT FROM C_procedure INTO @nom_procedure;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SET @RequeteSQL = 'EXECUTE ' + @nom_procedure + ' ' + @nom_schema_source
PRINT @RequeteSQL
    EXECUTE (@RequeteSQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM C_procedure  INTO @nom_procedure;
END;
CLOSE C_procedure;  
DEALLOCATE C_procedure;
```

**What i've tried so far :**

```
OPEN C_procedure;  
FETCH C_procedure INTO proc_name;  
FOR record IN C_procedure DO
    LET SQLRequest := 'EXECUTE ' + record.proc_name + ' ' + record.source_schema;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLRequest;
    FETCH record INTO proc_name;
END FOR;
        
CLOSE C_procedure;  
DEALLOCATE C_procedure;
```

Comment: I would, personally, ask if you *need* a cursor. That query looks open to injection too, especially when it could be written without dynamic SQL: `EXECUTE @nom_procedure @nom_schema_source` would actually just *work* in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Using both `OPEN FETCH` and FOR cursor loop at the same time has little sense in this context.

[Working with Cursors](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/cursors.html)

> When using a cursor in a FOR loop, you do not need to open the cursor explicitly.
>
> ...
>
> When using a cursor in a FOR loop, you do not need to close the cursor explicitly.

The equivalent of T-SQL `EXECUTE proc_name @params` is [CALL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/call.html) command and
[EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html) is used to execute dynamic SQL.

To avoid SQL Injection both procedure name and parameter should be parametrized:

```
DECLARE
   proc_name TEXT;
   source_schema TEXT;
   SQLRequest TEXT := 'CALL IDENTIFIER(?)(?)';

   C_procedure CURSOR FOR SELECT ...;
BEGIN
   FOR record IN C_procedure DO
     proc_name := record.proc_name;
     source_schema := record.source_schema;

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQLRequest USING (proc_name, source_schema);
   END FOR;
END;
```